# how to get user's location and display on the webpage in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on an angularjs web application where I need to get the user's location(latitude and longitude). This is the code in controller file:

```
var mylat= 0; var mylong = 0;
$scope.nearme = function($scope) {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

                mylat = position.coords.latitude; 
                mylong = position.coords.longitude;
                console.log(mylat);
                console.log(mylong);
        });
    }
}
```

This code works fine as the values are printed on the console.
How do I display these values on the webpage in the following manner:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Your Location: Latitude</td>
    <td>{{mylat}}</td> //show latitude
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Your Location: longitude</td>
    <td>{{mylong}}</td> //show longitude
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your $scope.nearme in your controller to the code below.

```
$scope.nearme = function() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

            $scope.mylat = position.coords.latitude; 
            $scope.mylong = position.coords.longitude;

    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'mylat' of undefined

Comment: could you please provide your complete code or a plunkr example, which will help mw find the root cause

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/12L87dO6FENqkeT4imMg?p=preview Check this plunker, your navigator.geolocation is going to a error callback

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/ISv6my67ONHMK2SRK95P?p=preview Please checkout this plunkr example. @Pramod_Para

Comment: Your navigator.geolcoation will have a success and a error callback. Your code is never entering into success callback, it is going into error callback. so you are not able to see the values in the view.

Comment: It prints coordinates on the console but doesn't display on the website.

Comment: Then how can I implement this? @Pramod_Para

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/s5cirSanxENA0RZf3fuS?p=preview , check this its working now